# Wix Installer - How to customize FatalError dialog based on server actions

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I need to display different messages in the FatalError dialog depending on what caused the installation to fail. My first attempt was to make the FatalError description text point to a property, and then set this property's value when an error appeared. The problem is that this dialog runs in the InstallUISequence table and the problematic actions in the InstallExecuteSequence table, and apparently the values that are set during InstallExecuteSequence are not copied back to the UI, and thus I'm losing them when the dialog is created.
Any ideas on how to solve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [custom action return values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369778%28VS.85%29.aspx). For example, if a custom action returns 1602  User Exit dialog will be used instead of fatal error dialog.

Another approach is to invoke ErrorDlg with a custom message. This can be done [MsiProcessMessage function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370354%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: I don't have much control over the CA return value. Besides I can't use other error codes because they have their own purpose and I need to be able to tell them apart (e.g. how do I know if a 1602 is a real user exit or it's one of my custom errors?).

Comment: About MsiProcessMessage: that would require rewriting the CA's, which is way out of my reach.